# How can I better manage a git repo for github pages that uses yeoman?

Tags: git, github, gruntjs, yeoman, github-pages

With Github pages for users and organizations, everything in the root of the master branch is what gets published. I am using yeoman/grunt to build my site and do not want to push my source files there.

When using something like the `webapp` generator, all of the public files are put in a `dist` folder.

Is there some way that I can keep all of my source files in a `develop` branch and merge the `dist` folder into the `master` branch and also change the path so that the files are in the root?

**UPDATE**

When looking up deployment ideas, I just stumbled across a [page on the yeoman site](http://yeoman.io/deployment.html) itself that talks about this, although it's for project pages and not user/org pages, I may have to modify it some. I will post back after I get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch):

```
$ git filter-branch --subdirectory-filter dist/ -f
```

Comment: I'm still getting into some of the more advanced features of git. Is this method preferred over the link I posted from the Yeoman site? I'm all for whatever is easiest to manage. Thanks.

Comment: @JoshKieschnick I'm curious whether you figured out how to push `dist` to a user/org gh-pages repo. I'd like to do the same, but am puzzled as to how to approach it, not to mention how to satisfy the need for the repo to be named `orgname.github.io` - thanks!

Comment: @ryancito Yes, I did. If you are using Grunt, [grunt-build-control](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/grunt-build-control) does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

Use `git submodule`.

Check the blog for [How to generate github pages in a submodule](http://blog.blindgaenger.net/generate_github_pages_in_a_submodule.html)

Comment: With this, I'm guessing for User/Org pages you just replace the gh-pages branch with master?

Comment: No. You don't wanna make default branch as `gh-pages`, rather your ph-pages branch will be submodule to master, check [my repo here](https://github.com/revathskumar/keralajs-promises/)

Answer (score 0):

FYI `gulp-webapp` has a recipe for this that works great. I switched from a user/org page to a project page to take advantage of it, and realized in doing so I didn't actually need a user/org page at all.